# Splitting large GPX file into smaller GPX files of 4.99MB each

Tags: google-maps, gpx

I have a large GPX file (> 5MB), which I'd like to import in Google Maps. Google Maps can only import GPX files up to 5 MB.

How can I split my large GPX file into smaller GPX files of 4.99MB each?

[image]

Comment: Check this link http://iamdanfox.github.io/gpxsplitter/

Comment: A GPX can contain a number of waypoints, tracks, and routes. Is it okay to split tracks? We don't know how many tracks you have.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you might not have a GIS platform. Simply convert the GPX to a CSV: https://anyconv.com/gpx-to-csv-converter/

Once you have the GPS values in the table, split and save them to use in Google Maps.